# how to auto delete data after new data has been uploaded on firebase on react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When a user updates their profile photo I want old data to be overwritten on firestore. I'm using firebase storage to store photos and upload firebase URL to restore database so

I tried filtering in on the front end side but I have multiple users to filter and there are a lot of duplicates

here is whole functionality of uploading data to firestore storage then updating firestore db and then pulling data with use

```
  const [userImg, setUserImg] = useState()

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
  const [htlmImg, setHtmlImg] = useState(null)
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null)
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState(null)
  const [sureLoading, setSureLoading] = useState(false)

   const [photoEdit, setPhotoEdit] = useState(false)
   const handleImageChange = (e) => {
   if (e.target.files[0]) {
    setImage(e.target.files[0])

    setHtmlImg(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
   }
  }
  const uploadImg = () => {
   const imageRef = ref(storage, `image${user.uid}`)
   uploadBytes(imageRef, image)
     .then(() => {
      getDownloadURL(imageRef)
      .then((url) => {
        setUrl(url)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message, 'error getting the image url')
      })
    setImage(null)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message)
    })
       setSureLoading(true)
     }
   const handlePfpSubmit = async () => {
  const { uid } = user
   if (url !== null) {
   try {
    await addDoc(collection(db, 'user'), {
      pfp: url,
      userName,
      uid,
      timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      time: Date(),
    })

    if (!photoEdit) {
      navigate('/test')
    }

    console.log('data send')
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
        }
     }
   }
    const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState(null)
     const [displayPhoto, setDisplayPhoto] = useState(null)
      const [userProfiles, setUserProfiles] = useState(null)
        useEffect(() => {
       const q = query(collection(db, 'user'), 
     orderBy('timestamp')).update()
     const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapShot) => {
      let photo = []
      querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
    photo.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
  })
  console.log(photo)
  console.log('data resived')

  let userUid = photo
    .filter((item) => {
      if (user.uid === item.uid) {
        return item.uid
      }
    })
    .map((item) => {
      const { pfp } = item
      return pfp
    })
     setDisplayPhoto(
    userUid.filter((val, index) => {
      if (userUid.length - 1 <= index) {
        return val
      }
    }),
  )
     let userUidName = photo
    .filter((item) => {
      if (user.uid === item.uid) {
        return item.uid
      }
    })
    .map((item) => {
      const { userName } = item
      return userName
    })
     let photoFilter = userUidName.filter((val, index) => {
    if (userUidName.length - 1 <= index) {
      return val
    }
  })
       setDisplayName(photoFilter)
        setUserProfiles(photo)
         console.log(displayPhoto)
      })
       console.log('re render ? ')

       return () => unsub()
     }, [user])
```

[image: database structure]

Comment: Which database are you using? Realtime database and Firestore are totally different databases. Also can you share a screenshot of your database structure and explain?

Comment: Which data actually gets updated ? I need a little more context

Comment: I added a database structure photo on my post, I'm using firebase, and what I'm trying to do is when a user updates their user name and profile photo I want old data to be overwritten by new ones so there won't be duplicate  user data when I display them on a front end side as other users

Comment: Yeah but why do you add a whole new document to the database when the user just updates the userName or profile photo? you can just use ```updateDoc(doc(db, `user/${user.id}`), { userName: theNewName, pfp: 'www.newurl.com'})```